# Getting a bug in Jetpack Compose when trying to render Text next to Icon composables

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

Rendering Text next to Icon composable:

```kotlin
@Composable
fun CourseCard(course: Course, modifier: Modifier = Modifier) {
    Card(modifier = modifier) {
        Box {
            Row {
                Image(
                    painter = painterResource(course.imageResourceId),
                    contentDescription = stringResource(course.stringResourceId),
                    contentScale = ContentScale.Crop,
                    modifier = Modifier
                        .size(68.dp, 68.dp)
                        .aspectRatio(0.5f)
                )
                Column {
                    Text(
                        text = stringResource(course.stringResourceId),
                        style = MaterialTheme.typography.bodyMedium,
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .padding(top = 16.dp, start = 16.dp, end = 16.dp, bottom = 8.dp)
                    )
                    Row {
                        Icon(
                            painter = painterResource(R.drawable.ic_grain),
                            contentDescription = null,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(start = 16.dp)
                        )
                        Text(
                            text = stringResource(course.numberOfItems),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(start = 8.dp)
                        )
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Course is just a data class:

```kotlin
import androidx.annotation.DrawableRes
import androidx.annotation.StringRes

data class Course(
    @StringRes val stringResourceId: Int,
    @DrawableRes val imageResourceId: Int,
    val numberOfItems: Int
)
```

Calling:

```kotlin
@Preview(showBackground = true)
@Composable
fun CoursesAppPreview() {
    CoursesTheme {
        CourseCard(
            Course(R.string.course1, R.drawable.course1, 58)
        )
    }
}
```

R.string.course1 is `Architecture` while the drawable is just an image associated with it.

I'm getting this text displayed instead of the string resource: [image]

I would expect the number 58 to be displayed as a `stringResource`.

Am I doing anything wrong?

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to use `.toString()`:

```kotlin
Text(
                            text = course.numberOfItems.toString(),
                            style = MaterialTheme.typography.labelMedium,
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(start = 8.dp)
                        )
```